# Kubernetes Nginx Preserve Source IP

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a few services running that require the Source IP to be preserved to perform authentication properly. I am running a Kubernetes environment in AKS using Nginx as my Ingress controller and am having problems understanding how I can implement this properly.

I read through this

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-typeloadbalancer

as well as this

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1067

And read that setting this service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy to Local should resolve my problem, but I am having a hard time understanding which Service I should apply this to. It almost sounds like this needs to be added to the nginx deployment and it would effect all deployments which is going to be undesirable.

My question is, is there a way to apply this to my Service manifests for just the services that need it and not blanket add this to everything either with Nginx annotations or adjusting the Service manifest for the services I am deploying?

For reference, here is my Service manifest I am deploying with helm:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ template "service.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "service.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "service.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}. #ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.service.targetPort }}
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: {{ template "service.name" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

Comment: I do have one of these services running on its own type of LoadBalancer to expose it with a public IP. I can patch it and add the Local annotation there, do I also need to do the same with the other web ui components and middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clearly need to add that setting to the `nginx ingress controller` service, the one with `type` = `LoadBalancer`.

If you think about it, there is no other option. `Nginx ingress controller` is the entry point in your cluster, so if you don't keep the source IP address there, there is no way you can have it in the services that come after that.

Comment: Right, I wanted to avoid a "global" change like that and limit the scope to its services. I also wanted to avoid adding another load balancer for this ingress point and was really hoping that I overlooked some annotation that would allow the specific value to be applied to the service instead.

I guess I was just hoping there was something I overlooked or if anyone had any better suggestions.

Comment: Not really, there is no wayout of this. On Azure, having multiple `Services` with `type = LoadBalancer` does not create a new LoadBalancer, but add another FrontendIPConfiguration to the existing one. That means that in theory you can deploy 2 ingress controllers in your cluster and have one dedicated to the backends that need client public IP visibility. Cost-wise it would be just one more public IP address. Is that an option?

Comment: Yea I was just thinking this, basically in our terraform that builds our current ingress controller on the last octet in the CIDR range, add another nginx ingress controller on the second to last octet of the CIDR and apply the configuration to this load balancer. 

Then deploy the service to this load balancer instead. 

Yea it is an option and would avoid making a global change as well.  Ill give that a shot and yea cost isn't a concern to be honest. I am just trying to think scalable and keeping away from anti-patterns. Which K8s doesn't say it is, but it almost sounds like one.